# Practica HTML y CSS

Tags: html5, css3

ahora el problema es el submenu del submenu no a parece el de recurso y luego el de los dos que aparece ali.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Y encantado por quien me ayude, le doy las gracias.

```css
/* Menú */

nav { 
  width:90%;
  max-width:1000px;  
  margin: auto; 
  margin-top:20px; 
  position:relative; }

nav ul { list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden; }

nav > ul > li { float:left; }

nav  ul  li  a {
  display:block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:red;
  font-family:'Oswall';
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a:hover { color:deeppink; }

nav > ul > li:hover div { display:table; }

/* Submenú 1*/

nav ul li .Submenu { 
  width:1000px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  background:cyan; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  display:none; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul { 
  width:20%; 
  display:table-cell; 
  border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  box-sizing:border-box; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul:last-child { border:none; }

/* SubMenú 2 */

nav ul li .Submenu { 
  width:1000px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  background:cyan; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  display:none; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul { 
  width:20%; 
  display:table-cell; 
  border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  box-sizing:border-box; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul:last-child { border:none; }

/* Sub-SubMenú */

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu { 
  width:1000px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  background:cyan; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  display:none; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu ul { 
  width:20%; 
  display:table-cell; 
  border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  box-sizing:border-box; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu ul:last-child { border:none; }

/* SubCategoría */

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu ul li .SubCategoria { 
  width:1000px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  background:cyan; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  display:none; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu ul li .SubCategoria ul { 
  width:20%; 
  display:table-cell; 
  border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  box-sizing:border-box; }

nav ul li .Submenu ul li .Sub-Submenu ul li .SubCategoria ul:last-child { border:none; }
```

```html
<html lang="es"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Tarea 2.6 - Kepriel</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"></head>
    <header>
        <h1 class="Cursiva">CIFP VILLA DE AGÜIMES</h1>
        <h4>CFGS ADMINISTRACION DE SISTEMAS INFORMATICOS EN RED</h4>
        <h4>LENGUAJE DE MARCAS Y SISTEMAS DE GESTIÓN DE LA INFORMACIÓN</h4>
        <h5>NOTICIAS TECNOLÓGICAS</h5><hr>
      <nav class="Negrita">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="p7.html">Noticias</a>
            
            <div  class="Submenu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#Horario">Horario</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA1">Noticia 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA2">Noticia 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA3">Noticia 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA4">Noticia 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA5">Noticia 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#NOTICIA6">Noticia 6</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            
          </li>  
          <li><a href="p7.html">Tareas</a>
            
            <div class="Submenu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="tareas/p1.html">Tarea 2.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="tareas/p2.html">Tarea 2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="tareas/p3.html">Tarea 2.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="tareas/p4.html">Tarea 2.4</a></li>
              <li><a href="tareas/p5.html">Tarea 2.5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
            
          </li>
        <li><a href="p7.html">Recursos</a>
            
          <div class="Submenu">  
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.cifpvilladeaguimes.es/">CIFP Villa de AgüimesS</a>
              
              <div class="Sub-Submenu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www3.gobiernodecanarias.org/educacion/cau_ce/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.gobiernodecanarias.org%2Fmedusa%2Feforma%2Fcampus%2Flogin%2Findex.php">Campus</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/educacion/9/PEKWEB/Ekade/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2feducacion%2fPEKWEB%2fEkade%2f">Pincel Ekade</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
              
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/educacion/web/">Gobierno de Canarias</a>
                
              <div class="Sub-Submenu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Enlaza</a>
                    
                  <div class =SubCategoria>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www3.gobiernodecanarias.org/medusa/proyecto/38700001-0002/">Información Proyecto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.cifpvilladeaguimes.es/moodle/course/index.php?categoryid=11">Areas de Enlaza en Centro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.cifpvilladeaguimes.es/proyectos/enlaza/enlaces">Enlaces</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                    
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.erasmusplus.gob.es/">Erasmus</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
                
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
            
        </li>
        <li><a href="mailto:kepriel@hotmail.com">Autor</a></li>
        <li><a href="Inicio.html">Acerca de</a></li>
        <li><a href="tareas/p3.html">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</html>
```

Comment: Cuando pasas con el ratón por encima el texto es blanco: `nav ul li a:hover { color:white; }` Cambia el color.

Comment: y esta cambiado el color me podrias ayudar con lo del submenu del submenu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplemente cambia

```
nav > ul > li > a:hover div { display:table; }
```

por

```
nav > ul > li:hover div { display:table; }
```

Comment: servio de utilidad pero ahorano me sale un submenu dentro de otro sub menu

Comment: es ahora el submenu del submenu es el que me da problema no aparece

Comment: Maryan, por favor explia mejor tu respuesta. Qué diferencias hay entre lo que tenia por lo que le sugieres?  Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo